# Can I use Amazon Textract or Amazon Rekognition for commercial use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, amazon-textract

I would like to use **Amazon Textract** or **Amazon Rekognition** API's for a SAAS I am developing.

But I could not find any clear description about whether it is permitted to use those services for commercial use without following any license condition.

I also looked at **Azure Computer Vision** and **Google Cloud Vision** and all I could find was [Google Cloud Vision API FAQs Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage) does not permit the resell of the Vision API, only that I can integrate Vision API into applications of independent value. Which I am also uncertain if applicable for my SAAS.

If anyone could shed some light about the licensing for theses services for commercial use I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you looking to resell the version or integrate it?

Comment: I am looking to integrate it into my own software, but users will be able to use certain features to extract text from scanned images.